# AWS API Gateway: Use mock integration to redirect

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

How do I create a mock integration in API Gateway to take a request to:

```
/products/{product}/bigFile.zip?platform={platform}&version={version}
```

And respond with a redirect to:

```
http://xyz.cloudfront.net/{product}/{platform}/{version}.zip
```

I've tried changing the request and response mapping templates, but I'm not sure how they're connected, since the AWS docs on mock integrations are pretty sparse. I can change the HTTP status code, but I can't get the `Location` header to populate based on the query parameters.

The broader context (in case I've committed the XY problem) is that I am building an API using AWS API Gateway. One of the API endpoints serves large files that won't meet the 10s response time limit from API gateway, so I want to redirect to another CDN link.

Comment: The timeout for API Gateway is not 10 seconds any more, it has been increased to 29 seconds (staying under the 30 second CloudFront timeout)

Answer (score 2):

For MOCK integrations, think about the Integration Request template that defines the status code (ex. {"statusCode": 200}) as a mock status code for the backend. Excluding that aspect, the other components are the same. You'll have to define a Method Response for the redirect 3xx status code and include any headers you want to send in the response. Then on the Integration Response page you can set the values for the headers as static values using single quotes. So that would be where you define the Location header with whatever the redirect URL is, like 'https://other.endpoint.com'

Edit: Workaround using Lambda function echo

Set up Lambda function to echo payload. Next map the querystring to the request body like so:

Template:

```
{
  "q": $input.params('foo')
}
```

Assuming the Lambda function echos the same payload back, you would set the header mapping source in the Integration Response as:

```
integration.response.body.q
```

Comment: I have the method request and response set up correctly, but it's the integration response I'm having trouble with. I can't use a static value for the header as you suggested, because I want to set the path in the header based on the request query strings.

To clarify my question, can I set some variables in the integration request template and access them in the integration response header?

Comment: Unfortunately you can't currently map request parameters to response parameters directly. If you were not using a MOCK integration then you could workaround the issue by echoing the querystring param via the backend then mapping the value from the response payload to the response header. I will add this to our backlog to explore mapping directly. Otherwise if you set up a simple Lambda function to echo the param, you could achieve the functionality.

Comment: @JackKohn-AWS do we still have to use lambda solution for this?

Comment: Yep, but I think we have a good idea how to support this the right way with MOCK integrations. Still don't have an ETA unfortunately.